# Make partially apply function from java function

Tags: java, scala, partial-application

I have java function like this

```
public static CollectionReader createCollectionReader(
        Class<? extends CollectionReader> readerClass, TypeSystemDescription typeSystem,
        Object... configurationData)
```

I'd like to make a partially apply function from this and specify some argument for Object... part. I am not sure if this is possible. I tried

```
val partiallyApply = createCollectionReader(_:Class[_ <: CollectionReader], _:TypeSystemDescription,
                                           "IncludeGoldStandardAnnotations", new Boolean("true"), 
                                           "EndIndex", new Integer("-1"), _:_*) // Doesn't work
```

and want it to be use as

```
val reader = partiallyApply(classOf[someReader], someType:TypeSystemDescription, 
"other", "configurationData", "beside", "those_four_that_already_applied_too"]
```

but this doesn't seems to work. Also, is this Object... has a technical name ?

EDIT: change code a little bit (my mistake .. I forgot to put val name in it) and add example of usage I want to.

EDIT2:I think my main question is that it is possible to do a partially apply function on vararg ?

EDIT3: Thanks to elbowich's suggestion. I come up with

```
def createCollectionReaderReadAll(cls: Class[_ <: CollectionReader], ts: TypeSystemDescription, cfg: AnyRef*) =
  createCollectionReader(cls, ts,
    Seq("IncludeGoldStandardAnnotations", new Boolean("true"), "EndIndex", new Integer("-1")) ++ cfg: _*)
```

work perfectly fine

Comment: The `Object...` is called a [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html#varargs).

Comment: unclear - are you trying to create the method definition in scala or do you want to invoke the java method? the scala code you have offered has multiple flaws starting with a missing val name :-) let me know of what you are trying to do and i'll try to help! btw Object... is same as AnyRef*

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. I couldn't believe I forgot to put name in val...

Comment: np :) is it possible to do a partially apply function on vararg - not directly, but varargs translate to arrays so you should be able to pass an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can partially apply varargs, I'd do it like this:

```
def method1(x: Int, cfg: String*) = cfg
def method2(x: Int, cfg: String*) = method1(x, Seq("preset", "cfg") ++ cfg:_*)
```

Comment: That's wrong, it's perfectly possible to partially apply varargs, e.g. def tag(name: String)(attrs: Tuple2[String,String]*)(body: String*) = { etc... }

Comment: @AlanBurlison unfortunately that's not what I meant, but while we're at it: how one puts placeholder for `attrs` in your example?

Comment: additionally, to my surprise, it's possible to do stuff like this: `def m(xs: Int*) = xs; val f = m(1, 2, _: Int)`, but looks like  placeholder itself can't be a vararg